# Parsing '?' in getopt

Tags: c

```
void display(char * str){
   printf("%s: Missing file\n", str);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int longIndex, opt = 0;
    const char *optString = "h?";

    static const struct option longOpts[] = {
    { "help", no_argument, NULL, 'h' },
    { NULL, no_argument, NULL, 0 }
    };

    opt = getopt_long( argc, argv, optString, longOpts, &longIndex );
    while( opt != -1 ) {
        switch( opt ) {
            case 'h':
            case '?':
                display(argv[0]);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        opt = getopt_long( argc, argv, optString, longOpts, &longIndex );
    }

        return 0;
}
```

This code compiles fine but when I run it like:

```
./a.out ?
```

it does not call display. What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the -. Options all start with -. ? is not an option. (Actually it's a shell metacharacter which will match any single-character filename, so it might not be passed to your program at all. Try ./a.out -? (and pay attention to the other comments about ? returned by getopt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question mark '?' is returned by **getopt** when it finds an argument *that's not* in the **optstring** or if it detects a missing option argument, so you shouldn't use '?' in **optstring** because it's sort of reserved for that, instead you should use the more conventional 'h' for help.

See the [man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

Edit:
This is an example:

```
switch (opt) {
    case 'n':
        some_flag = 1;
        break;
    case 'h': /* help */
    default: /* '?' unknown opt or missing arg*/
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [-n nsecs] \n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: How do I display the message then for '?'?

Comment: I meant you shouldn't use it as part of the optstring, because getopt will then return '?' when a) it sees an unknown option b) there's a missing arg c)it sees the '?' character, but you could use it in a switch case of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you include -? with --help on your help message, leave the question mark out of your call to getopt, leave it out of the case option, and make sure that --help is the first case option in your list, the question mark works as you'd want it to.

Answer (score 0):

1. Stop getopt() from producing its own errors. (Leading : option)
2. Handle -h separately.
3. In the error case (?) test for the "errored" option of '?'
4. Do not use default to handle a getopt() known parsing errors. Default is your code bug.

   ```
   while ((c = getopt(":hf:")) != -1) {
   switch (opt) {
   case 'n':
       save_value = optarg;
       break;
   case 'h': /* help */
       help();
       return -1;
   case '?'
       if (optopt == 'f') {
           fprintf(stderr, "Option -%c requires an argument.\n", optopt);
       } else if (optopt == '?') {
           help();
           return 0;
       } else {
           fprintf(stderr, "Invalid option -%c.\n", optopt);
       }
       help();
       return -1;
   default:
       fprintf(stderr, "Parsing err0r.\n");
       help();
       return -1;
   }}
   ```

Answer (score -1):

const char *optString = "h?";

Above line replace with following line

const char *optString = "h\?";

this is the literal of question mark in C language